# How to split a label into multiple lines if it's too wide

Tags: c#, string, winforms, label, messagebox

I want to make my own message box, here are it's constructors:

```
    public MBX(string message)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MBX(string message, string title)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MBX(string message, string title, string[] buttons)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

I would like to make a void that will reformat the message to have a width less than 444.
Here's an example to help you out:
Let's say that the message was: `"abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc"` and that this string had a width greater than 444 pixels, what the void is going to do, is to split it into multiple lines until the width is lower than 444 like so:

```
abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc
abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc
abcabcabcabc
```

(You can keep in mind how the original message box reacts to long strings)

Thank you in advance!
VBTheory

**EDIT:** After searching for a couple of weeks, I was able to find an article that treats exactly this word wrap issue: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51488/Implementing-Word-Wrap-in-C#_rating

Comment: Have you tried [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring.aspx)

Comment: I know how to get the length of a string, the problem is knowing where to add the new line to split it

Comment: Are you sure? it is not the same as `string.Length`. Just loop till you get a value less than 444.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the length of the string, if it is greater than 444, use the substring function to parse the full string from 0 to 444, and from 444 to string.Length().  If the second substring is still greater than 444, lather rinse and repeat.  Put the strings into a string array, and to display in the message box, loop through the array inserting a new line escape character after each string element.

Answer (score 0):

For GDI+ there is [`Graphics.DrawString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring.aspx) which will be better to use if you want GDI+ features. It has these formatting options: [`StringFormatFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformatflags.aspx)

You can use it to wrap the text for you by supplying it with with a rectangle to wrap the text into. This is probably your best bet.

[Here's a good example of how to wrap text using `Graphics.DrawString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baw6k39s.aspx)

Alternatively, for GDI you have [`TextRenderer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exkzzayx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

[`TextRenderer.DrawText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160657%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) gives you a lot of control over the layout via the [`TextFormatFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textformatflags%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) setting.

Also, you can use `TextRenderer.MeasureText()` to measure text accurately. It uses the same calculations as `DrawText()` so you can use them together.

Answer (score 0):

`TextBlock` has wrapping options instead of `Label`.

```
<TextBlock
     Text="abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc"
     TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```